# Making the "Next Step" field required when changing the stage of an Opportunity?

Tags: opportunity

What would be the easiest way to make it required for a user to update the "Next Step" field whenever they attempt to change the stage of an Opportunity? I think making the field required only forces it to be filled when the opportunity is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation rule would be something like:

AND( 
ISCHANGED(OpportunityStage), 
NOT(ISCHANGED(NextStep)) 
)

So it basically reads "If OpportunityStage is being changed, but NextStep is not being changed, display a validation error."

Comment: field is `stageName`

Answer (score 2):

Use the ISCHANGED() formula on the field you are referencing.  You can then require something to change on the field to save the record.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing this?